# HQL Many to Many how to query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

i have two entities : `Customer` and `User`. They have a many to many relationship. Assume I have the following data in database.

```
Customer
-------------
id  | name 
1   | customer

User
-------------
id  | name 
1   | user1 
2   | user2 

Customer_use
-------------
customer_id  | user_id
1            | 1
1            | 2
```

My question is how to return a query result like below:

```
customer | users 
customer | user1,user2
```

Comment: HQL depends on the classes, not the tables. So the structur of the tables are not that important then the structure of the entities. If you don't know how to map it, ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the joins you can fetch the records by single HQL query for more reference [click here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

Comment: i want to know how to concat the user's name to one string ,

Answer (score 1):

HQL is object oriented, which means that you return objects. If you want to return all customers, just do `select c from Customer c` and all its  relationships comes with the object.